# Saving many subsets as dataframes using "for"-loops

Tags: r

this question might be very simple, but I do not find a good way to solve it:
I have a dataset with many subgroups which need to be analysed all-together and on their own. Therefore, I want to use subsets for the groups and use them for the later analysis. As well, the defintion of the subsets as the analysis should be partly done with loops in order to save space and to ensure that the same analysis has been done with all subgroups.

Here is an example of my code using an example dataframe from the boot package:

```
data(aids)
qlist <- c("1","2","3","4")
for (i in length(qlist)) {
    paste("aids.sub.",qlist[i],sep="") <- subset(aids, quarter==qlist[i])
}
```

The variable which contains the subgroups in my dataset is stored as a string, therefore I added the qlist part which would be not required otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a list of the subsets with lapply:

```
lapply(qlist, function(x) subset(aids, quarter==x))
```

Equivalently, avoiding the `subset()`:

```
lapply(qlist, function(x) aids[aids$quarter==x,])
```

It is likely the case that using a list will make the subsequent code easier to write and understand.  You can subset the list to get a single data frame (just as you can use one of the subsets, as created below).  But you can also iterate over it (using `for` or `lapply`) without having to construct variable names.

To do the job as you are asking, use `assign`:

```
for (i in qlist) {
   assign(paste("aids.sub.",i,sep=""), subset(aids, quarter==i))
}
```

Note the removal of the `length()` function, and that this is iterating directly over `qlist`.

Comment: Is there a way, I can store those lists as dataframes with standardized names such as aids.sub1 to aids.sub4? I have more than 300,000 obs. which cannot even be all printed on screen.

Comment: You can, but you probably should not.  I'll edit the answer to show how.

Comment: @Lonelyisland you can name the lists. You can access them by `object$name` and it won't clutter your workspace with "useless" variables.